# Does the strength of a rock cored from a borehole increase while waiting in atmospheric conditions?

Tags: geoengineering

Does losing moisture of a cored rock sample will increase its strength? Or drying out make the core specimen weaker. If the rock is a clayey rock, it will be weaker. But  what about for other rocks? Will their strength in uniaxial compressive strength test or point load test increase when comparing its strength with its in situ conditions, Say its under 100 m of the ground level and saturated.

Comment: No expert on this but some rocks dewater when removed from the ground such as jet and they become harder, though I suspect most would be softer.

Comment: Coring rock - particularly from depth releases the lithostatic pressure and can cause the core to break apart, particularly along bedding or foliation planes. The rock may already be under tension but not break apart until removed from the surrounding material